# How to reverse an irreversible migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
```

I have this in my devise migration, Now I have rollbacked the migration ..I got an error of

```
`StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`
```

Now I cannot access the model, even after rake db:migrate. How to make this work again?

Comment: Probably, my recent post can be a solution of this issue: http://localhost:3333/rerun-stale-migration/

Answer (score 0):

> An Irreversible Migration is not meant to reverse

You can't reverse an irreversible migration.

So, if the migration is `Down` and you want it to migrate `Up` just comment the contents in `up` method and run the migration again.

While commenting the contents will make sure the queries or command won't run again giving you another error

Answer (score 0):

Irreversible migration can be reversed at a SQL level. write an ALTER query to change the column or anything else in rails console by

```
ActiveRecord::Connection.base.execute('your ALTER query')
```

After that delete your migration file.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit to the migration file and changes the `change` method by `reversible` and run again the migration.